# High [Data out] in short period of time. Azure website

Tags: azure, web

i'm a new user at azurewebsites service and i'm encouraged why my website send too much data out. Server has 55GB data out in 8 hrs. My website does not contains any big files, its just a visit-card website.
How i can inspect what happens?
graph here http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/server.1360266996.png

Answer (score 2):

You can enable **Web Server Logging** in Windows Azure Website (Configure tab).

[image: Diagnostics]

When the logs are enabled you can download them via FTP (address to your logs FTP can be found on the main - *dashboard* tab.

[image: Windows Azure Web Server Logs]

You will find all necessary details from the Web Server Logs like resources were downloaded and how many bytes were sent etc.

I hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks, i enabled logging, but already one hour past, and no log files inside folder on ftp. Already 130GB data out...( i'm thinking about disabling web server, I'm losing money each hour :(.

Comment: I think it was web-scanner like skip-fish or dos attack, is any way to check access.log on azurewebsite?

Comment: so, logs appeared now, i can see someone downloading file 500kb from my server 16.000 times in a hour =/ how i can block him? can i automatically ban IPs with high traffic on windowsazure ?

Comment: Yes, you can block specific IP address. Have a look at `IP Security` IIS settings: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity. Also you can find more info and scenarios in different blogs e.g. http://blog.liamcavanagh.com/2011/10/how-to-block-ip-addresses-in-windows-azure/. I hope that will help. Otherwise you may end up with very bid bills from Azure.